# How to do full body detection and tracking in a rectangular frame using c# and kinect

Tags: c#, kinect

I am working on a project using c# and Kinect in which I want to detect the entire body and then track its motion in the video using a rectangular frame (just like we have mobile cameras focusing our faces in a rectangular frame and tracking our motion). Can anyone help me with some coding hint?

Answer (score 0):

For the quick start just use these [quick start series](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart) it contains all what you need to get a start. You don't need a separate rectangle. when the Kinect tracks it's skeleton you can put a separate rectangle using the left most and right most joint positions to get the rectangle's two verticle ends and top most and bottom most Y positions to horizontal limits.

Comment: How can I get the position coordinates as they will change every time the body moves.

Comment: when you get a one joint you can have it's x,y,z coordinates. by this you can get the coordinates of any joint. you can find how to do this from the above quick start series.